# How do I return instances of Interface<T> when all I have is T?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface:

```
public interface ILoginResult<T> {
    public T get();
}
```

I have a `LoginPage` object:

```
public class LoginPage<T> {

     ...

     public ILoginResult<T> login(...) {
          ...
     }

}
```

I also have some landing page objects, the possible places that `login` can lead to. They implement the interface:

```
public class Page1 extends PageBase implements ILoginResult<Page1> {

     ...

}
```

These are the kinds of objects that the `login` method must return. The type of object returned should match the type that was specified when the `LoginPage` was created.

I am not sure how I can go from the type `T` to an instance of `ILoginResult<T>`. I can create instances of objects that implement specific types of `T`, but this doesn't satisfy the return type. Am I trying to do something that has no common, standard method of implementation, or am I just missing something obvious?

**Additional Data:**

This is a bit of test automation. LoginPage is a page object, which can login to one of a number of different pages depending on various settings. `T` represents one of these landing pages, which are all subclasses of a `PageBase` superclass.

In my old code, the `login` method returned a specific subclass of `PageBase`. I would log in to a page - say `Page1` - thusly:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(...);
Page1 page1 = (Page1) loginPage.login(parameters);
```

I have been instructed to introduce more type safety and avoid the casting using the above interface. Presumably the code would then look like:

```
LoginPage<Page1> loginPage = new LoginPage<Page1>(...);
Page1 page1 = loginPage.login(parameters);
```

My difficulty lies in creating and returning instances of these objects that satisfy the return type `ILoginresult<T>`. I can create instances like `Page1` that implement `ILoginResult<Page1>`, but this is too specific.

Comment: T is just a placeholder for a specific type (Integer, String, Long, etc.). When actually declared, an instance of ILoginResult<T> will have a specific type mentioned in the angle brackets, like ILoginResult<Integer>. Other than that, you treat it the same as any other interface.

Comment: Indeed. My issue is that, the `login` method must return an instance of type T. I have to write a method that returns this instance of T without knowing what T is.

Comment: Essentially, you just use the same code but replace specific class names (Page1, etc.) with T. You can refer to the Java tutorial trail on Generics for more information. Somewhere along the line you will pass in an actual Page1 (or whatever) type though. By the way, another thing I want to point out is that T in ILoginResult should be thought of as different from T in LoginPage. They can be the same, but it depends on how they are called. If ILoginResult is always passed the T inside of LoginPage then they will be the same.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try simply creating an object?

```
public class LoginPage<T> {
    public ILoginResult<T> login(...) {
        final T t = ...
        return new ILoginResult<T>() {
            @Override 
            public T get() { 
                return t; 
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 And to clarify to the reader - this example uses an anonymous implementation of `ILoginResult`.

Comment: I think the crux of my question centers around the line `final T t = ...` in your example. I have concrete implementations of `T`. But I can't put `final T t = new Page1(...)`. I need to somehow get from the generic `T` in my LoginPage to an instance of that type which is then returned.

Comment: @rironin You might want to consider using the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) then. You can create an interface like `public interface Factory<T> { public T create(); }` and pass it into `LoginPage` when it is created.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with the factory pattern, but in a sense, I feel like I'm attempting to implement the factory right here in the `login` method. It is a factory for `T`, or for `ILoginResult<T>`. If I were to create a factory I'd have the exact same problem, no? "Given T, create an instance of T."

Comment: @rironin It's going to depend on your exactly problem whether the factory creates `T` or `ILoginResult<T>`. The point of the factory pattern is that somewhere down the line you're going to have a `LoginPage` with a concrete type parameter (let's say `Integer` for the sake of the argument). Then when you create the `LoginPage<Integer>`, you'll have to pass a `Factory<Integer>` to `LoginPage`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create an implementor of `ILoginResult` and `T` will be substituted while creating the `LoginPage` instance

```
public ILoginResult<T> login() {
     ILoginResult<T> i = new ILoginResultImpl<T>();
     return i;
}
```

where

```
class ILoginResultImpl<T> implements ILoginResult<T> {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I have several concrete implementations of landing pages, say, `Page1`, `Page2`, `Page3` - each of which implements `ILoginResult<Page1>`, `ILoginResult<Page2>`, etc, respectively. Can my login method return instances of these concrete classes?